# How to control "update trigger" in oneway databinding in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, 2-way-object-databinding, data-binding

When using databinding in WPF, if you set `Mode` property to `TwoWay`, you can control the moment when the source property will be updated by setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` property. That scenario is possible for target -> source update stream. But how you can control same thing for source -> target update stream? I cannot find equivalent property.

For example, lets say I have two textboxes on my window, and I want to bind Text properties of both textboxes. XAML may look like this:

```
        <TextBox
            Name="txt1"
            Text="{Binding ElementName=txt2, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
            />
        <TextBox
            Name="txt2"
            />
```

When user enters text in `txt1` TextBox, `Text` property of `txt2` Textbox will be updated as `Text` property changes, just if I had implemented TextChanged event on `txt1`.

However, when user enters text in `txt2` TextBox, `Text` property of `txt1` Textbox will be updated after `txt2` TextBox looses focus because `UpdateSourceTrigger` property is set to `LostFocus`, just if I had implemented LostFocus event.

Is there possibility in WPF databinding to update target property after source property control looses focus? In our example: what should be done to XAML code above, so `Text` property of `txt2` TextBox would be updated only after `txt1` TextBox loose focus, and not after its Text property changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not define two bindings? This works for me:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="txt1" Margin="4" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=txt2, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBox Name="txt2" Margin="4" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=txt1, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UpdateSourceTrigger` mechanism is linked to the implicit nature of a WPF control. In this way you can decide when update the source.
On the other side the source can be a `UIElement`, but it can be another object too. Indeed an object which is the source of a binding, can notify its changes to the binding, by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
With this interface the object notities its changes *everytime* a property changes.

So if you want a kind of "UpdateTargetTrigger" you should implement it in a control.
For example you can extend the TextBox control in this way:

```
public class ExtTextBox : TextBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
    private string textOnLostFocus;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            propertyChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            propertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        SetTextOnLostFocus(Text, false);
    }

    private void SetTextOnLostFocus(string text, bool updateText)
    {
        if (StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(textOnLostFocus, text) != 0)
        {
            textOnLostFocus = text;
            if (updateText)
            {
                Text = text;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("TextOnLostFocus");
        }
    }

    public string TextOnLostFocus
    {
        get
        {
            return textOnLostFocus;
        }
        set
        {
            SetTextOnLostFocus(Text, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the TextOnLostFocus as a support to notify its changes just on LostFocus event.
Therefore your XAML will be:

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" Text="{Binding ElementName=txt2, Path=TextOnLostFocus, Mode=TwoWay,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Margin="3" />
<local:ExtTextBox x:Name="txt2" Margin="3" />
```

I hope it can help you.